# TypeError not all arguments converted during in Python-mySql

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a question why I get this error.
I try to insert some data from my python script into mysql.

This is my code:

```
queryinsertStatus = "INSERT INTO general (status) VALUES (%s, )"
onlinestatus = (y["msg"])
print(onlinestatus)
cursor.execute(queryinsertStatus, onlinestatus)
```

But as result I get this:

```
API online

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 204, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trading.py", line 30, in <module>
    cursor.execute(queryinsertStatus, onlinestatus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
```

What do I wrong? onlinestatus contains a "API online"

mySQL is of type tinytext

Hopefully someone can helpme.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, you should NOT have a comma in your SQL (`VALUES (%s)`), but you DO need a comma in your parameter.  The `execute` method expects to get a tuple.  `(y["msg"])` is just a string.  To make it a one-element tuple, use `(y["msg"],)`.

This is just a weird corner of Python.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such a small detail can be the pain in the *ss.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement itself appears to be problematic - that "," doesn't seem to belong in the VALUES section. Maybe try it like this:

```
queryinsertStatus = "INSERT INTO general (status) VALUES (%s)"
```